# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\MainController::sendEmailDoneR(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected

Tags: php, laravel

I send an Email to verify and it gives me that error.

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\MainController::sendEmailDoneR(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected
```

This is my sendEmailDoneR Code.

```
function sendEmailDoneR($verifytoken, $rvid, $tischid){
        $verifytokenc=DB::table('reservierung')->select('verify_token')->where('rvid', ''.$rvid.'')->value('verify_token');
        if($verifytoken==$verifytokenc){
            $this->setverifiedR($rvid, $tischid);
        }
        else{
            //mit error zurückgeben
            return view('verificationfailed');
        }
    }
```

And this my web.php.

```
Route::get('verifyr/{email}/{verify_token}', 'MainController@sendEmailDoneR')->name('sendEmailDoneR');
```

This is my EmailView.

```
<p>Just one more step until you can start creating a profile for your restaurant!</p>
<p>Please verify your E-Mail by </p><a href="{{route('sendEmailDoneR', ["verifytoken"=>$verifytoken, "rvid"=>$rvid, "tischid"=>$tischid])}}">clicking here</a>
```

I can access that variables in the Email already tried that!

Comment: `'verifyr/{email}/{verify_token}'` should match `($verifytoken, $rvid, $tischid)`. Anything inside a `{}` in your routes file are URL parameters, and are passed to the function. You only have 2 values inside `{}`, but 3 parameters inside the function declaration. One of those is wrong, so fix it :)

Comment: Side note, you don't need the quotes/concatenation on `where('rvid', ''.$rvid.'')`. Just pass `$rvid`, and it will work fine.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you i figured it out. I had to add one more value in my web.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only setting two variables in you web.php [email','verify_token']

```php
Route::get('verifyr/{email}/{verify_token}', 'MainController@sendEmailDoneR')->name('sendEmailDoneR');
```

but the controller is expecting three

```php
function sendEmailDoneR($verifytoken, $rvid, $tischid)...
```

so no matter what you're sending in your view:

```php
<a href="{{route('sendEmailDoneR', ["verifytoken"=>$verifytoken, "rvid"=>$rvid, "tischid"=>$tischid])}}"
```

the `web.php` is only passing two to your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the controller function in this way:

```
function sendEmailDoneR($verifytoken, $rvid, $tischid) {
```

But your route does not match these parameters.
Your route should be:

```
Route::get('verifyr/{verifytoken}/{rvid}/{tischid}', 'MainController@sendEmailDoneR')->name('sendEmailDoneR');
```